# How to detect colors or texture of specific shape from the physical image in ARkit, RealityKit?

Tags: augmented-reality, arkit, realitykit

The End user will have a coloring book with different things like airplanes, cars, animals, etc. they can use multiple colors to color them, I have to detect each of these physical images and the colors or texture from the physical image and apply them to the model. Please point me in the right direction.